# How to properly read stream of bytes with frame boundaries with error processing in F#?

Tags: error-handling, io, f#

I am new to F#, and need help to solve this problem.

I have a stream of bytes, which come from serial port and represented as sequence in F#. Stream consits of frames, each begins with 0xFE and ends with 0xFF. Bytes transmitted continuously and for synchronization I must skip some bytes until 0xFE. But stream may be corrupted and may lack the 0xFE or 0xFF.

I have a function that is iterated through input from the serial port. The code of function is:

```
let getFrame s =
    let r = s |> Seq.skipWhile (fun x->x<>0xFEuy) 
              |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x->x<>0xFFuy)
    if Seq.isEmpty r then r else Seq.skip 1 r
```

How can I rewrite this code to skip bytes until 0xFE or skip certain number of bytes and if no 0xFE occured return error in functional way?

The same is tru for take frame bytes until 0xFF.

Comment: You might want to edit this question to add some examples. Also my understanding is that you need help writing functions for skip from start to 0xFE, and skip from 0xFF to end, not processing errors.

Comment: @GuyCoder, yes, You are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following function does what you want. The input stream consists of garbage and frames. Gargabe can come first or between frames. An error is reported if there is either too much garbage or if a frame is too long. Otherwise the next frame is returned.

```
let [<Literal>] FrameStart = 0xFE
let [<Literal>] FrameEnd = 0xFF

let [<Literal>] MaxGarbageLength = 5
let [<Literal>] MaxFrameLength = 5

type State<'T> =
| Garbage of int
| Frame of int * 'T list

let getFrame stream =
    let getNextRest stream =
        match Seq.isEmpty stream with
        | true -> None
        | false -> Some(Seq.head stream, Seq.skip 1 stream)

    let rec parse state stream =
        match getNextRest stream with
        | None -> None
        | Some(next, rest) ->
            match state with
            | Garbage n when n >= MaxGarbageLength -> None
            | Garbage n ->
                match next with
                | FrameStart -> parse (Frame(0, [])) rest
                | _ -> parse (Garbage(n+1)) rest
            | Frame(n, _) when n >= MaxFrameLength -> None
            | Frame(n, content) ->
                match next with
                | FrameEnd -> Some(content, rest)
                | _ -> parse (Frame(n+1, content @ [next])) rest

    parse (Garbage 0) stream
```

To get two frames from a stream:

```
[<Test>]
let ``can parse two frames with garbage in between``() =
    let stream = Seq.ofList [1;2;3;FrameStart;4;5;6;FrameEnd;7;8;FrameStart;9;0;FrameEnd]

    let (frame1, rest) = (getFrame stream).Value
    frame1 |> should equal [4;5;6]
    rest |> should equal [7;8;FrameStart;9;0;FrameEnd]

    let (frame2, rest) = (getFrame rest).Value
    frame2 |> should equal [9;0]
    rest |> should equal []
```

Errors are correctly detected by returning None (note MaxGarbageLength is 5, so the following reports an error):

```
[<Test>]
let ``none is returned when there is too much garbage``() =
    let stream = [1;2;3;4;5;6;FrameStart;7;8;9;FrameEnd]
    (getFrame stream).IsNone |> should equal true
```

This seems to work and should be easy to extend/modify. But it looks like quite a bit of code to me. Improvements welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Option<'T>` type as a result of your function, where `Some x` would mean that some frame was captured form input sequence and `None` that no frame data was found:

```
let getFrame s =
    let r = s |> Seq.skipWhile ((<>) 0xFEuy) 
              |> Seq.takeWhile ((<>) 0xFFuy)
    if Seq.isEmpty r then None
    else Some (Seq.skip 1 r)
```

However correct failure handling implementation depends on the semantics of your `getFrame` function. For example, what if the `0xFE` is present, but there's no `0xFF`? Does that mean that this isn't a data frame? Does that mean that the data frame was split accross many sequences? Etc.

Comment: thank You for answer! But how can I correctly stop skipWhile in case of garbage in stream and no 0xFE (frame start) in it, for example in first 1000 bytes. Аnd how can I distinguish correct frame start from error (no 0xFE found) in case of skipWhile stop?